# using variables existing in interface in classes which implements the interface

Tags: java, variables, interface

I have an interface.There are three classes which implements this interface.

In the interface , i have two variables like:
double x;
double y;

Now, what can i do with x and y in these three classes. In these class objects , can i use their own x and y value ?(i can't use it , if there is a way , tell me please) can i change it in any way ?

I'm confused about the interfaces . What can i do for the variables inside the interface in the three classes which implements it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick google, variables defined in an interface are seen by the JVM as public final static. So you can access them by Interface.x but can't set them. This makes sense, since an interface is used to define things, not to *be* things.

http://www.coderanch.com/t/408233/java/java/Instance-variables-interface

Comment: yes , i know it is final however i need to use different x and y variables in classes which implements the interface.

Comment: You will have to add them to the classes implementing the interface, you can force classes to have certain member variables.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.. because interface variable are public static final.

You can access it in a static way using your

```
InterfaceName.x and InterfaceName.y
```

You can not the change the values once assign them because these are constant.

Comment: in all classes which implements the interface , are the all x and y values are the same ?

Comment: I have different classes and i need different x and y values . However, there is no alternative other than define x and y in the interface

Comment: @user1308990 Just make a class have two variable x and y. Assign different value according to your requirement.

Comment: making a class ? Where ? i cannot understand what you mean

Comment: @user1308990 In place of interface make a single class and put these variable in it.

Comment: inside the interface or inside the .java file with the interface?